# Disabling button until process is complete - Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I have a page where users can place orders, Order numbers increment.

Is it possible to disable the button until the process is complete? i.e until the order is successfully placed.

What my clients face is, when they click on the place order button, the process becomes slow since their network is bad. Unknowingly, they click the place order again assuming the process failed. At the long run, they will have orders of the same items (duplicates). `001, 002, 003` all having the same food items since they keep clicking on the place button.

**Code**

```
 public function save(Request $request)
 {
    $food = new Food(array(
        'name'  => $request->get('name'),
        'price' => $request->get('price'),
    ));

    return redirect('admin')->with('status','Order successfully placed');
}
```

Comment: How are you submitting the order? If you are using ajax then you can disable the button before the ajax query and then enable it again once the client receives a response. Your question is lacking important detail and source code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: Post the code of submitting the order pls

Comment: @NewToJS, i save my order the standard way its been done in laravel for `store` not with ajax. Kindly check my update

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz please check my update

Comment: You could disable the button with javascript and add a loading icon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can disable form's submit button after clicking on submit button using jQuery.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('submit', 'form', function() {
        $('button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Why `jQuery` for such a little task you have written? What you have written could be done without having to include/load the `jQuery` library.

Comment: It's not necessary to use jquery library. You can use javascript as well. Generally jquery is used with each website now a days that why I have  answered with jquery.

Comment: I agree, `jQuery` is very common but it isn't tagged in this question and that might be for a reason.

Comment: Ok I didn't look on tags. But I think that helped him.